# import java.net.http.HttpRequest, import java.net.http.HttpResponse, and import java.net.http.HttpClient not working

Tags: java, android-studio, httprequest, httpresponse, importerror

I'm making an app in Android Studio using Java and I want to access an API url, so I need HttpRequest, HttpResponse, and HttpClient. However, none of them are importing. [Here's a picture of what the import statements look like right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0sg3.png) I have Android Studio 2020.3.1 and Java 11.0.10. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I think it's because Android uses HttpsURLConnection instead of all those other ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Android does not provide all features of the JDK, it's just a subset of it. Since HttpClient was introduced in Java 11 and Android does only support Java8+ partly the API is not available yet, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table

You can use [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) as an solid alternative.