# How to Solve HttpClient Error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpclient, okhttp

Full code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnTurn;
private boolean state = false;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
public String mUrl = "http://192.168.6.56/server_http/api/show.php/";
public String data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnTurn = findViewById(R.id.btnTurn);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stateCheck();
            Log.d("Logger", "State Check");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);

    btnTurn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!state){
                btnTurn.setText("Turn Off");
                state = true;
            }else{
                btnTurn.setText("Turn On");
                state = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void stateCheck(){
    if (state){
        if (bluetoothAdapter!=null & bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if(checkCoarsePermission()){
                Log.d("Logger", "Discover");
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkCoarsePermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action= intent.getAction();

        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            String RSSI = String.valueOf(rssi);
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"rssi "+RSSI+" "+device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Logger", "Recive data "+device.getAddress());
            data = "RSSI: "+RSSI+" MAC: "+device.getAddress();
            try{
                GetText(mUrl,data);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("Logger","Error Function to send");
            }

        }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
        }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this,"ALLOWED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Forbidden",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } break;
    }
}

public void post(String urll, String dataa) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(urll))
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(dataa))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.discarding());
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
}
}
```

Problem of code

[image: Picture of problem]

Error

[image: Error]

I want send RSSI and MAC of Bluetooth scan using HTTP protocol, i used method HttpClient as plain java in Android Studio Java. But in my case, the code will error. I don't know why. I was included library and gradle in my android studio but still error. Anyone can help me how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: @MatteoNNZ wait, i will edit my question to show my import statements

Comment: For one thing, you don't seem to define a `GetText` method.

Comment: @RyanM waw you deleted my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the screenshots you posted, it looks like you're pointing to the classes of the package `org.apache.http`, but from the methods you use in your code, I think you rather want to use `java.net.http` classes.

So simply fix your import statements on top of your class, from:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
//etc.
```

to:

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
//etc.
```

Comment: hmm, but suggestion about import statement from org.apache.http . Maybe im wrong to implement dependencies?

Comment: Can you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344568/import-java-net-http-httprequest-import-java-net-http-httpresponse-and-import ? My problem related with this description after change to java.net

Comment: @AndroidE On which Java version are you running? java.net.http package is available natively from Java 11, but I'm not sure if before that release you need to add a dependency to your build.gradle (if IntelliJ doesn't propose you to import it, it's because it's not in the classpath and that can only mean it's not in the JDK and you didn't add the required dependency)